# Center The Leftover Item From The Last Row In GRID (1fr 1fr)

Tags: css, css-grid

This is something that I've been struggling with for a while, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

If you have an odd number of items in grid and you want 2 items per row (1fr 1fr), you end up with a single item in the last row that is left-centered.
I just want to make it centered so it looks nicer.

[Here's a picture too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgoM1.png)

Comment: Please post your code here and try to create a [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I made this codepen as an example https://codepen.io/diva_codes/pen/eYJgxrp

Comment: I took one of the divs out of the grid to get the layout I want to get (to be able to show you) if I were to have all items inside the grid.

Comment: updated my answer based on your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/tn1562ep/2/):

```css
/* visibility properties */
body {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}
div {
  margin: 3%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-self: center;
}
div:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: red;
}

/* actual code: */
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

#last-div {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div id="last-div">
</div>
</section>
```

Get more info on CSS Grid: [complete-guide-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work at first, but I was experimenting with a bunch of different elements, and idk what I did, but I got it to work so... I'm done touching that section :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this since I faced a similar issue in one of my earlier projects.

```
grid-template-columns : repeat(auto-fit, minmax(<minSize>, 1fr));
```

Set minSize to whatever minimum width you want an element to occupy.